# trying to print the contents in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to `print` the html `contents` to a new `window`.

```
var w= window.open();
var htmlContent = $(printdiv).html(printcontent);
$(w.document.body).html(htmlContent);
$(w).location.reload();
$(w).focus();
$(w).print();
$(w).close();
```

I am a getting a `blank window` with no `html` contents instead?

Comment: I think the single origin policy would prevent you from altering the content of another window...

Comment: I am not alterting, but just trying to print... a clone/copy of it.

Comment: I don't think that would matter, I think you'd still be prevented from accessing any of it.

Comment: @freak_head What is `printcontent` ?

Comment: I stand totally corrected, I overestimated the abilities of the single origin policy, ignore me.

Comment: @NeilMunro _"single origin policy would prevent you from altering the content of another window"_ Would the origin of new `window` be `opener` of new `window` ? Not appear that `var w = window.open("", "w");` is different origin ?

Comment: I'm pleasently surprised to have been wrong and learned something, just wanted to ensure I'd corrected my original position, lest it lead to confusion to anyone reading it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting new `window` name reference , removing `$()` wrapper around `w` at `.focus()` , `.print()` , `.close()` as `jQuery()` does not have method `.print()` calling `.print()` chained to `$()` would return `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
// set `w` name reference
var w = window.open("", "w");
var htmlContent = $(printdiv).html(printcontent);
$(w.document.body).html(htmlContent);
// $(w).location.reload();
w.focus();
w.print();
w.close();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/14f5owux/