# Print Div with overflow: auto; in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a huge html page, want to print it using javascript.

Did tried as below by passing div id to the function

```
function printDiv(divID) {
    var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + divElements + " </body>";  
    window.print();  
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

It is printing only first page content of a div. How to Print whole page?

Please suggest me.

Comment: Appear to be setting `html` element as childNode of `body` element at `document.body.innerHTML = "<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   " +
    divElements + "
  </body>"` ? Also note no closing `</html>` tag ? To set `html` try `document.documentElement.outerHTML = "<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   " +
    divElements + "
  </body></html>"` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210555/trying-to-print-the-contents-in-a-new-window

Comment: It not helped me . 
In my case, child div contains overflow:auto property . Still it is printing single page.

Comment: I think scroll in child div is causing the issue. How to remove the scroll only during printing?